# AS3: weird dynamic text bug

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text

I'm working on a game and weird bug happens, when i want to display scores.

For example it shows 5 instead of 75. It happens sometimes, not regularly and only for a moment, until variable will change again.

The code is simple:

`point_txt.text = String(points);`

When I check variable "points" with trace(); it shows correctly.

Anyone got the same problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: Is it always the same letters that are missing? If so, make sure you are embedding all characters that are needed. By default, Flash will only embed the characters that are already used in textfields on the stage in the IDE. It could be the case that you use most (but not all) numerals in placeholder text etc.

Comment: It's 7, 9, 0, but not always and it's embeded.

Comment: sounds like some characters aren't embedded if the trace is the correct number

Comment: do you have a default value set on your text field?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

```
point_txt.text = String(points);
point_txt.width = point_txt.textWidth;
```

Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't. Textfield width isn't problem. The better example of this bug will be showing 35 instead of 305.

Answer (score 0):

Change from the Properties panel Behavior: Single line